# Transformar linhas em colunas no SELECT Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Segue abaixo um select para consulta de dados em uma tabela:

```
SELECT
'OS:'||AT.CD_NUMERO_OS ||' ITEM:'|| AT.ITEM ||' ETAPA DA ATVD:'||AT.CD_ETAPA_ATIVID||' ATVD:'|| AT.CD_ATIVIDADE AS "DADOS DA OS",
AT.DT_INICIO AS "DATA DE INICIO",
AT.DT_TERMINO AS "DATA DE FIM"

FROM GMATIVID AT

INNER JOIN GMOSERVI OS ON OS.CD_NUMERO_OS = AT.CD_NUMERO_OS

WHERE OS.DT_OS BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data_abertura_os_inicial, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:data_abertura_os_final, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND OS.SITUACAO LIKE 'E'

ORDER BY AT.CD_NUMERO_OS ASC, AT.ITEM ASC, AT.CD_ATIVIDADE ASC
```

Abaixo segue o resultado dessa consulta:

[image: Resultado da consulta]

Preciso transformar as linhas em colunas para encaixar no relatório report que estamos desenvolvendo, segue abaixo como preciso da informação:

[image: Consulta necessária]

É possível realizar essa "transposição" de linhas em colunas diretamente na consulta SQL?

Comment: Pesquise pir PIVOT ou CASE PIVOT https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html   https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot

Answer (score 1):

Com PIVOT você resolve isso.

Exemplo :

```
SELECT d.department_name, e.job_id, count(e.employee_id)
FROM hr.employees e
INNER JOIN hr.departments d
  ON d.department_id = e.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_name, e.job_id
ORDER BY d.department_name, e.job_id
;

WITH values_join
AS
(
  SELECT d.department_name department_name, e.job_id job_id, e.employee_id qty_empl
  FROM hr.employees e
  INNER JOIN hr.departments d
  ON d.department_id = e.department_id
)
SELECT * FROM values_join
  PIVOT
  (
  COUNT(qty_empl)
  FOR job_id IN ('AC_ACCOUNT','AC_MGR','AD_ASST','AD_VP','FI_ACCOUNT','FI_MGR','HR_REP',
                 'IT_PROG','MK_MAN','MK_REP','PR_REP','PU_MAN','SA_MAN','SA_REP',
                 'SH_CLERK','ST_CLERK','ST_MAN')
  )
ORDER BY department_name
;
```